# I got an error message in my script, I don't know how to fix it

Tags: r, error-handling, syntax-error, economics

I am trying to run a panel VAR model with this script but I get an error message:

```
varone <-pvargmm(
 dependent_vars = c("dEMBI"),
 lags = 2,
 exog_vars = c('dPBI','dINF','dRATE','dBC','dDF'),
 transformation = "fd", #puede tener 2. fd es la 1era diferencia y fod es forward diferention
 data = df,
 panel_identifier = c("ID", "Year", "Month"), #q variables sirven para identificar el panel. Tienen que    ser números
 steps = c("twostep"),
 system_instruments = TRUE, #Default
 max_instr_dependent_vars = 99, #Default 
 min_instr_dependent_vars = 2L, #Default
 collapse = FALSE #Default
)
```

It was supposed to estimate the model but I get this error:

```
   Error in intI(i, n = di[margin], dn = dn[[margin]], give.dn = FALSE) : 
 index larger than maximal 90
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?